# Javascript, shoot laser only once

Tags: javascript

I want the function shootLaser(); to only fire once, the below code is a failed attempt to use a variable to control the shootLaser() by only alowing it to shoot once after I hit the space bar but not again if I hit the space bar again; by using a variable that increments once the laser is shot once. Was wondering how to implement this?

```
function keyBoardInput() {
var i = event.keyCode;


  if (i == 32) {
  var g = 0;
    if (g < 1) {
       shootLaser();
     g++;/**now that g is incremented IF statement shouldNOT allow shooting?**/
    };
  };
```

Comment: Every time `keyBoardInput` is invoked, `g` is reset to `0` by this line: `var g = 0;`.

Comment: `g` is set to 0 every time...

Comment: function keyBoardInput() {
     var i = event.keyCode;

      var g = 0;
      if (i == 32) {
      if (g < 1) {
   shootLaser();
   g++;
   };
   
  
    };

Comment: its still fireing every time i hit space bar even when i took G outside of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always redeclare `g` to 0, so it will always be less than 1. Put the `var g = 0` outside the function.

Comment: there you go, just marked yours as the answer, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Still new to JavaScript myself but I think that the variable g is local scope to the function so that every time the function keyBoardInput is run it resets the var g back to 0. If it was contained in a closure so that the var g would retain its value that might work, or if the variable was outside of the function so that the function doesn't reset it each time.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the declaration `var g = 0;` outside of the function. That way it won't get set to 0 each time. See example below:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup',keyBoardInput);
  var g = 0;
function keyBoardInput(event) {
var i = event.keyCode;
  if (i == 32) {
    if (g < 1) {
       shootLaser();
     g++;/**now that g is incremented IF statement shouldNOT allow shooting?**/
    }
  }
}
function shootLaser() { 
      console.log('shooting laser');
}
```

```html
Press space to fire the Laser
```

One simplification you could do is to move the incrementing of g into the if statement - since it is a post-increment, it won't affect the value until after the conditional:

```
if (g++ < 1) {  //g will now be incremented and we checked if it was less than 1
    shootLaser();
}
```